# Chrome removes property value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I think I've run into a possible bug in chrome, but wondering if this is something I'm doing wrong. I am collecting data from an IndexedDb and adding this to an array BUT one property was always empty so I started debugging.

Below is my code for the `onsuccess` function and below that is a print screen of one of the rows from my `console.log` with one property marked with yellow. Notice how this exists and has a value!

On my second image which is when I "open" the object in chrome developer tools to see how it looks, I noticed that `Title` is undefined. What am I missing? What causes this behavior?

This exact code is working on the same site, just another page.

```
cursorRequest.onsuccess = function (evt) {
        var cursor = evt.target.result;
        if (cursor) {
            var pushItem = true;
            if (opts.searchCriterias && opts.searchCriterias.length > 0) {
                pushItem = false;
                for (var i = 0; i < opts.searchCriterias.length; i++) {
                    if (opts.searchCriterias[i].values.contains(cursor.key)) {
                        if (opts.includeKeyInResponse == true) items.push({ key: cursor.primaryKey, value: cursor.value });
                        else items.push(cursor.value);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (pushItem) {
                if (opts.includeKeyInResponse == true) items.push({ key: cursor.primaryKey, value: cursor.value });
                else {
                    items.push(cursor.value);
                }

                console.log(cursor.value);
            }
            cursor.continue();
        }
    };
```

**Title exists and have value**
[image: Strange Image 1]

**Title exists but is undefined (This is same as above, just expanded)**
[image: Strange image 2]

Comment: Could you put together a StackOverflow snippet to reproduce?

Comment: I tried but the problem cannot be reproduced in JsFiddle. It is working perfectly when I add it to any fiddle.

Comment: That would suggest that there's a bug somewhere in your code rather than the DevTools. You might need to spend a little longer trying to isolate the offending code.

Comment: I would agree on that, except the fact that showing compressed object in Dev Tools is showing the Title, and expanding it sets it to undefined. How can my code have anything to do with that? I wish it is my code because then it is something i can amend myself.

Comment: Does this object inherit from anything else? Whats the prototype look like? Maybe conflicting variable names?

Comment: Hi, no it does not inherit from anything but can it be that when it is printing the compressed row, it is that current state, while if i click it, it first looks it up against the memory and present the current data if it has been changed afterwards? If so, the problem might lay later in the code?